# Rounded shape as background for button not showing correctly

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've a round shape like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

and I'm using it as background for buttons

```
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/like"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

and in android studio preview it showing a round button

[image]

but In application I'm getting this

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which android version are you using to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check the java code which I was setting color as background of button and after removing that part of code it's working great

Answer (score 1):

Increase the radius in background drawable file...

Comment: it's not working. in other activities I've used this background it's showing correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to define each corner separately...
Instead of `raduis` define all: `bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius, topLeftRadius, topRightRadius`

Comment: it's not working. in other activities I've used this background it's showing correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Try to set smaller width for button